# How do I make the console print things one at a time in C++ the way Java and Python do?

Tags: c++, printing, console

I'm trying to get a feel for C++ by creating a program to efficiently find [highly composite numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number), but I'm facing an inconvenience. The console waits and then prints everything at once. I want it to print things one at a time like Java and Python do. How do I do that?

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    int record=0; //Highest number of factors found in a number so far
    for(int n=1; n<2147483647; n++){
        int factors=1;
        for(int PPF=2; PPF<=n; PPF++){ //PPF="Possible Prime Factor"
            bool isPrime=true;        
            for(int i=2; i<PPF; i++){ //
                if(PPF%i==0){         //Determining if the PPF is prime
                    isPrime=false;    //
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(isPrime){
                if(n%PPF==0){ //Here is where I calculate the number of factors n has based on its prime factorization.
                    int PRP=1; //PRP="Prime Raised to Power"
                    int pow;
                    for(pow=1; n%(PRP*PPF)==0; pow++){ //Finding the exponent of a specific prime factor
                        PRP*=PPF;
                    }
                    factors*=pow;
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(factors>record){
            record=factors;
            std::cout<<n; //Print the highly composite number
            printf("\n"); //Gotta make a new line the old-fashioned way cuz this is a low-level language
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running this on VS Code with CodeRunner and all the necessary C/C++ extensions.

Comment: Replace `std::cout<<n; //Print the highly composite number
            printf("\n"); ` with `std::cout << n << std::endl;` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

More precisely, you need `std::flush`. `std::endl` prints a line break and flushes, but flush does so without the break. You can also print to `std::cerr` which is not buffered and prints everything directly.

Comment: Well I do happen to want the line-break. What does it mean that `std::cerr` isn't buffered?

Comment: buffered input is exactly what you have been experiencing. To save time, data is gathered up, buffered, and then dumped to the underlying media in large blocks when the buffer is full or a flush is requested. Buffering is often whole orders of magnitude faster than one write after another, and it's the default for regular streams because why use C++ if you don't want peak performance?

Comment: @zucculent it's the buffering that causes the delay.  C++ uses a buffer for output for efficiency, and usually only writes the output when the buffer becomes full.

Comment: @infinitezero This answer contains a solution to the issue, but starting an answer with *"More precisely..."* is not a good idea. It's unclear which content you're referring to. In the given context I assume its a comment. However comments have their own lifetime and could be gone at any time. It would be better to post the statements you're referring to at the start of the question, e.g. *"Replacing line X with Y would work, more precisely you need to flush...."*